# Checking adjacent indices in 2 dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

I have to write minesweeper.
I've figured out a way to check the adjacent indices to count how many bombs surround the current index without going out of bounds. But it's long, ugly, and most likely inefficient.
They're just a bunch of conditional statements for each unique cell that could potentially reach out of bounds. My question is, is there a shorter way to do this? And would implementing a 1 dimensional warp-around array make it any easier/harder?

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++){
        **// index 0,0**
        if (i == 0 && j == 0 && field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
        }
        **// index 0,9**
        else if (i == 0 && j == HEIGHT - 1 && field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
        }

        **// index 9,0**
        else if (i == WIDTH - 1 && j == 0 && field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i - 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
        }

        **// index 9,9**
        else if (i == WIDTH - 1 && j == HEIGHT - 1 && field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i - 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
        }

        **// if first row**
        else if (i == 0 && (j != 0 && j != HEIGHT - 1) && field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
        }

        **// if last row**
        else if (i == WIDTH - 1 && (j != 0 && j != HEIGHT - 1) && field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
        }

        **// if first col**
        else if (j == 0 && (i != 0 && i != HEIGHT - 1) && field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i - 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
        }

        **// if last col**
        else if (j == HEIGHT - 1 && (i != 0 && i != WIDTH - 1) && field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i - 1][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
        }

        **// Cells that are fully surrounded**
        else if (field[i][j] != 10){
            if (field[i - 1][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i - 1][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j - 1] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j] == 10)
                count++;
            if (field[i + 1][j + 1] == 10)
                count++;
        }


        if (field[i][j] != 10)
            field[i][j] = count;
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a similar question that might prove useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381284/multi-dimensional-array-how-can-i-check-all-adjacent-tiles-that-are-in-bounds-t The accepted answer on that question uses short-circuit evaluation to check just four cells - up/down/right/left - but you should be able to expand it to work with all 8 surrounding cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard way to deal with such situations - define an array with your valid moves and iterate over it. Here is an example how you can iterate over 8 neighboring cells:

```
static int moves[8][2] = {{-1,0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}};
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
      for (int l = 0; l < 8 /*sizeof(move) / sizeof(move[0]) */; ++l) {
        int ti = i + move[l][0];
        int tj = j + move[l][1];
        if (ti < 0 || ti >= WIDTH || tj < 0 || tj >= HEIGHT) {
          continue;
        }
        // cell (ti, tj) is valid neighbor do something with it.
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that's cool. I would've never thought to put the valid moves inside an array. Thanks. Btw inside the if statement it should be ti < 0. Otherwise it doesn't test cells inside the first row. Thanks again